# 10.7 Builds work incorrectly when build on 10.8

Tags: xcode, osx-lion, osx-mountain-lion, afnetworking

I am having quite a bit of a problem just explaining my problem. But in short. I have a very simple project, and the only outside code I use is AFNetwork.

When the app opens, I open a simple login window. It has a subview which contains username field and password field, and OK and Cancel button. Everything works smooth in 10.8. When I build the app and copy it to 10.7 machine, all clicks register lower than I actually click. So if I want to put the cursor to the username field, I have to click almost 20-25 pixels higher, if I want to click the OK button, I have to click at 20-25 pixels above the button.

If I build the project on 10.7, the clicks are correct, but as soon as I set NSMutableRequest, I am thrown into assembly code in the debugger and I have no idea what is happening, except it stands on [str length] inside the debug view on the left, main thread.

I have gone over every xib settings, no auto layout is set, no view has layers, all is set to be compatible with 10.7. Build clean, Project -> Archive has been tested.

I am just at my wits ends here.

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't just debug this in Xcode in the normal way ?

Comment: I've tried that, step by step. The clicks are impossible to debug, but the hard crash just happens, line goes to nsmutablerequest, bamm, just by setting it, which is just weird

Comment: OK - thanks - that makes the picture a little clearer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problems seem to have been mostly because I had in awakeFromNib, [self.view setWantsLayer] which works as expected (for an iOS developer) on 10.8 but does strange things in 10.7.

If you want layers, either do it in Interface Builder or subclass, it is the safest way.